# Unable to delete pages when using FragmentStatePagerAdapter - What is the usual behavior of row ID's when integer primary key is used?

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, android-contentprovider, rowid

**Please feel free to skip to the question as this background understanding may not be necessary for you.**

I am new to android and sqlite and I am designing an app which has a content provider to access an sqlite database with multiple tables. There are several activities which use different adapters to display info from the database to the UI (i.e. cursor adapters, fragment state page adapter and array adapters).  I have been having issues with the delete function in all of my activities which don't use the cursor adapter.  When I try to update or delete a row from a table it deletes the wrong row or it doesn't delete anything at all. I believe it is a problem with the adapter where I am trying to figure out which row it is to send the correct info to the content provider.

The identical java code works perfectly with the cursor adapter and the rows delete normally and the other CRUD operations work. The insert and query functions work normally for all tables.The provider code uses a switch statement for each table but it is basically identical for each Uri case. All of the tables have _id as the integer primary key which is NOT set to auto increment.  Since I don't fully understand how the row id works my java code does not reflect it and I keep having these issues. Although I have read many documents about content providers, adapters, sqlite databases, etc. certain key details are not clear to me.

My question is **how does the row id get assigned numbers in the database when it is set to _id column as a primary key and what happens to those numbers when the database is changed?**

For example, say I have an empty database.  Initially after inserting the first row, the Uri will return a path segment for the 0 row and the adapter position would be 0... what would the row id for the database be (0 or 1) ?

Then for each row I insert, I know that row number would increase by one integer. Say I insert 4 rows - 0,1,2,3.   Now when I am ready to delete - should the last path segment on the Uri be one integer less than the row number (i.e do I send a Uri with a last path segment of 2 to delete row 3)? Finally, after deleting, will the row ids then automatically get re-assigned so that row 4 now becomes row 3 ? Is there some code that I need to write to make that happen in the database? The primary keys are not set to auto increment.

I have different adapters and activities to where I can not access the actual database row ID once the data is displayed in the UI, so I am using the adapter position as a surrogate. This is why I am having trouble with update and delete.
Thank you very much if you read this entire question and take the time to answer it, it would help me tremendously.

I have an activity that is tabbed and uses FragmentStatePagerAdapter that is populated by a database. Here is the Adapter that I adjusted to keep track of the rows:

```
  **EDITED:**

   public class TankSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> tankFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> tankTitles = new ArrayList<>();

//I added this ArrayList below to store the tankIDs to match the Fragments//

**public ArrayList<Integer> tankIDs = new ArrayList<>();**



public TankSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return tankFragments.get(position);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tankFragments.size();
}


@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position) {

    return tankTitles.get(position);
}


public void addPage(Fragment fragment, String tankName) {

    tankFragments.add(fragment);
    tankTitles.add(tankName);

   // I added this below so the ID position would match each fragment position //

    **tankIDs.add(tankId);**

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
// Finally I added this method below to the adapter//

   **   public ArrayList<Integer> getPageId(){
  return tankIDs;
     }**
```

Here is the activity where the method is called and where it pulls the data from the cursor to pass to the Adapter. There is a loop where each row creates a page(tab) in the ViewPager:

```
 public class MyClass extends Tank implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

public TankSectionsPagerAdapter tankSectionsPagerAdapter;

TabLayout tabLayout;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_class);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

    addPages(mViewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

}


    public void addPages(ViewPager mViewPager) {

                              tankSectionsPagerAdapter = new TankSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(tankSectionsPagerAdapter)

        try {
    ...
                                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE_TANK_SETUP, MyDatabaseHelper.ALL_TABLE_TANK_SETUP_COLUMNS, tankDataFilter, null, null);

                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {

    tName =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.TANK_NAME));                ...

    // all the variables are stored in the bundle passed to the   fragment/
                                                                                                                                            ...                  

                                                               **tankSectionsPagerAdapter.addPage(MainTankFragment.newInstance(tankBundle),tName, int tankID);**

  tankDataFilter = tankDataFilter + (-1);
                                }
                                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                                cursor.close();
                            } else {
                                Toast...
                            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast..
    }
       }

   ...   

  // Get Row ID from cursor(tankID), parameter in addPage() above//



//Get ID's from Adapter //

    ** ArrayList <Integer>  pageID= tankSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageId();**
```

This is the Activity with Spinner to choose the rows/fragments to edit or delete.

```
public class EditTank extends Tank  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
     ...


 // Get the ArrayList//

   ArrayList<Integer> IDtags =getIDIntent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("tank_edit_key");

    loadEditTankSpinnerData();


////***Here is the Spinner. Use row ID from the ArrayList****** 
           Note: Don't use the id of the spinner


       editTankSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view int position, long id) {


     *** tankID = IDtags.get(position); ***           

        }




   private void loadEditTankSpinnerData() {

    List<String> tankNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE_TANK_SETUP, MyDatabaseHelper.TANK_NAMES, null, null,null);
    try{
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tankNames.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            deleteTankBtn.setEnabled(false);
            editTankBtn.setEnabled(false);
            Toast...
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast...
    }


 ...
}
```

The above code worked well with CursorAdapter but not with the fragmentStatePagerAdapter (***Prior to the edits it did not work, now it works well and deletes correctly).

I spent days(weeks) on this because I didn't understand  why the rows weren't deleting. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: have you seen the last parameter of `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` method?

Comment: Yes, I do see what you mean, the last parameter is id.   However I have some activities which don't use the onItemClick directly. For example, I have a tabbed activity which uses fragment state pager adapter to add fragments based on a loop of the cursor pulling from the database. I use a spinner to indicates which fragment is being selected based on the tab name (I have not figured how to get the id from the tab directly onTabSelected).  However when the item is selected and the id is retrieved from the spinner, it does not lead to deletion of the correct row in the database.

Comment: When the column is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it always is autoincrementing. And you must not use the position in the list, this would not work with a filtered/sorted list.

Comment: `Spinner#getSelectedItemId()`

Comment: Thank you both.  I just used spinner.getSelectedItemId()  instead of the other way I was getting the Id.  It worked for me to get the Id and delete the first row but then when i went to delete the second row it would not work (The database had two rows in it). The last row would not delete.  I have logs throughout telling me the path so I know that the path is set to row 0. But I guess in the database the last row is row 2.

Comment: `"but then when i went to delete the second row ..."`, what second row?

Comment: I created two sample entries in my database. The first row deleted fine. The second row did not delete. That is why I wanted to know what happens to the database rows after a delete (Do they move up or stay in the same place?) However even with the code definitely pointing to the correct row it does not delete so I have to conclude there is another reason why it isnt working.

Comment: so what IDs did you get from `getSelectedItemId`? before passing a `Cursor` to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` what do you see on the logcat if you call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`?

Comment: I didnt use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor, but I can try that.  I just logged the id and Uri strings

Comment: I got 0 when I selected the first entry and 1 with the second. After delete I got 0 for the remaining row (with log of strings). With database utils the output was android.content.Content.Resolver$CursorWrapperInner@256bb31.

Comment: ids of `SimpleCursorAdapter` are stable, if your `Cursor` had 0 and 1 (did you dump your cursor?) and you deleted id == 0 and reloaded the adapter (`SimpleCursorAdapter#changeCursor`) you should have one item with id == 1, i think you should post your code, otherwise its gonna be empty talk

Comment: Ok thanks I will post. It's not the cursor adapter that I am having issue with its the fragment state pager adapter

Comment: so we are not talking about the `Spinner`? yes, better post your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, @CL, and @albeee - this is what I learned from you guys and my own research.

In order to delete rows from database which is populating FragmentStatePagerAdapter or ArrayAdapter you have to be able to link the correct row with what is being displayed in the adapter. Otherwise the rows won't delete or will be inconsistent or incorrect. The CursorAdapter will automatically handle the watching for changes and selecting the ID for you. If you can use CursorAdapter or a direct onItemClickListener and get the id directly from the AdapterView with getSelectedId() or just long ID, then that is a good way to get the row ID. However, if you are getting the id indirectly by other means then you have to handle the associations...

1.**You should not use the adapter position, spinner position or even spinner id to select the row.  These are useful only to determine which item/fragment you want.** Only the ID of the OnClickListener on the item itself will consistently give the correct row.

2.**The database rows behave as such - the integer primary key will auto increment even if AUTOINCREMENT is not chosen, but the row ID's are stable once assigned.** This means that each new row will have a higher ID than the last but if you delete rows in between, it will not change the IDs of the remaining rows.  So the rows will skip and not be consecutive when there are edits and deletions. For this reason you must have a method to link the item to the ID permanently. There may be a better way to do this, however, I will edit the code above to show one way that I was able to do it for the FragmentStatePagerAdapter so the user can add and delete fragments dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Word of advise - Try to write your question as simple as possible also the code. You shouldn't share too much code in here. People will just ignore.

1. You're using a CursorLoader but not using it properly. Use the LoadFinished method's cursor data.
2. Then you can directly pass the cursor to your FragmentPageAdapter and use it directly there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks. I will shorten my code more. :')I read the documents for OnLoad Finished but I dont understand how it can help me in deleting the row. I do understand better now how the row ids behave and I believe that will help me solve the issues.